# Using Phantom.js evaluate, how can I get the HTML of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backbone.js, phantomjs

```
page.evaluate(function() { return document; }, function(result){    
    console.log(result)                    
    next();
});
```

result is actually a huge object. I don't know the properties and attributes of that object. I just want the HTML of the page `as you would see it in Chrome inspector`.

From the look of the object, it seems that the HTML includes CSS and javascript..which is weird. The user should not see the CSS and javascript, because they are not the web page's HTML.  Those are external files. I only want the HTML that the user would see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `document` is an HTML document. To get the entire DOM as a string, you could do `document.documentElement.outerHTML`.

From outside `evaluate`, you can use `page.content`. It is a string.

I don't know what you mean by "HTML includes CSS and JavaScript" or "the web page's HTML". Are you referring to the difference between the page source and the DOM as modified by scripting? Both the above give you the current DOM, not the original page source.

Comment: Thanks. The HTML is printed.  However, the page that I'm evaluating is a Backbone app. How come I don't see the views rendered into the HTML.  It's as if the javascript didn't run at all.

Comment: It's hard to say without more information, but it is possible that you are accessing the HTML before initialization code has had a chance to run. Make sure you are accessing `page.document` in the callback you provide to `page.open`. You could try adding a time-out for fun as well.