# How to parse a HTML page after waiting for JS to load the content?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I want to get the source code of a HTML page, but it has a JS script that loads the data dynamically and attaches the received content to the page.

I am using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) to parse HTML, but it only returns the content before the JS execution, so I do not receive the dynamically loaded data.

How can I get the source code after the script execution using any framework, cli, etc?

Comment: something like document.getElementById("elementid").outerHTML after the item is rendered.

Comment: Show how this JS script looks like.

Comment: Best bet is to run it through Phantom and use Phantom's `page.content`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706777/using-phantom-js-evaluate-how-can-i-get-the-html-of-the-page/16706908#16706908.

Comment: Please specify what framework you're using, share some code, and mention what you tried so far

Comment: You could parse the url where the content is being loaded from

Comment: JavaScript does not change HTML source. It sounds like you're looking for an HTML dump of the page DOM, as modified by all load-time Javascript. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
$(window).load();
```

Which will wait until the page is loaded.

Another option:

```
function whenAvailable(name, callback) {
var interval = 10; // ms
window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (window[name]) {
        callback(window[name]);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
    }
}, interval);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
whenAvailable("jsLoadFunction", function(t) {
// do something
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use load event of window.
Example :

```
window.onload = function(){
        /*Parse Html*/
}
```